# How to run an executable from within emacs on windows

Tags: functions

I have a program, say myprogram.exe, and I want to run it from within Emacs by using a key binding. I can run the program in the shell, but don't know how to write a function that calls this function and can be assigned a key binding.

Thanks

Renger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give here only the basic ingredients as a starter kit.

Define an [interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) command [that calls `myprogram.exe`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html):

```
(defun myprog ()
 (interactive)
 (call-process "myprogram.exe"))
```

Now [bind that command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html) to the key of your liking:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") #'myprog)
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias,works like a dream (I had written a script that sends a line from emacs to matlab and returns, so I can use matlab-mode and matlab on my windows machine)

Comment: @arnyeinstein The standard way to indicate that the answer solves the problem is to accept it. (Click the green check mark.)